# Loading Large Datasets in Parallel With Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

TLDR;

1. I want to read many files from disk in parallel
2. My code loads these files very quickly, but merging them into the main process' memory is slow
3. Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way to share memory across processes?

Background:
I'm currently working on a project with a private hospital dataset (only 3 GB!) and would like to be able to load it faster (their disks are slow). I work on a 36 CPU server, so I should be able to speed it up using multiple processes. However, I am having trouble seeing an improvement.

The setup:
I have split my dataset over 12 binary PyTorch files ('.pt') which I load with `torch.load(filename)`. These files each contain a list of images inside a dict E.G. the 0th list: `{0:ListOfImages}`. I would like to load these files simultaneously with different processes, then merge them into a list in their original order. I am currently able to do that, but cannot seem to merge the data into the main process faster than it would take to load sequentially.

Sequential baseline load: 74 seconds

What I tried:

- `multiprocessing.Pool().map()` (150 Seconds)
- multiple iterations of `process.start()` + `process.join()` (300 Seconds +)
- multithreading: I load the dataset in exactly the same amount of time as sequentially (74 Seconds)

Multiprocessing code thus far:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
CORES = 12

def loadWorker(sharedDict,filename):
  t1 = time.time()
  temp = torch.load(filename)
  print("Dict Loaded in :{} seconds".format(time.time()-t1))
  t1=time.time()
  sharedDict.update(temp)
  print("Dict updated in :{} seconds".format(time.time()-t1))
  

filenames = ["namingconvention{}.pt".format(i) for i in range(CORES)]

jobs=[]
manager = mp.Manager()
sharedDict = manager.dict()
t1 = time.time()
for i,filename in enumerate(filenames):
  print("starting Process: {}".format(i))
  p = mp.Process(target=loadWorker, args=(sharedDict,filename))
  jobs.append(p)
  p.start()

for i,proc in enumerate(jobs):
  print("join Process {}".format(i))
  process.join()

print("dict created of length: {} in {} seconds".format(
  len(sharedDict),time.time()-t1)
)
  
images = []
for i in range(CORES):
  print("Appending Images: {}".format(i))
  images = images + list(images)

print("Images appended in {} seconds".format(time.time()-t1))
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to share memory between these processes?

OUTPUT:

The output of the above:
[Image of the stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdCHq.png)

The output of the above code with `CORES=1` and `logger.setLevel(mp.SUBDEBUG)`
[Image of debug stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlytf.jpg)